# Get most favorited (many to many) records in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an app where users can favorite venues, this is done via a many to many relationship with a "favorites" pivot table.

Now I want to retrieve the top 10 most times favorited Venues with Eloquent.

My models:

```
//User model

public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Venue', 'favorites', 'user_id', 'venue_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }

//Venue model

public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'favorites', 'venue_id', 'user_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need the third and fourth argument to `belongsToMany()`. Also you should name your table `user_venue` to fit with conventions and then you can get rid of the second argument too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this :

```
$venues = Venue::withCount('favorites')->orderByDesc('favorites_count')->take(10)->get();
```